# Phalcon & Volt: Adding hasMany()/belongsTo() conditions, and counting linked rows

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I have two tables in my database, `form_settings` and `webmaster`, that are on a one-to-many relationship, and this has been defined in their Models.

**FormSettings.php**

```
class FormSettings extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{    
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('db_table', 'webmaster', 'db_table');
    }
}
```

**Webmaster.php**

```
class FormSettings extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{    
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('db_table', 'form_settings', 'db_table');
    }
}
```

In my Controller, I perform the following `find()` and pass it to the view:

**ControllerBase.php**

```
class ControllerBase extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $exhibitions = FormSettings::find(
            array(
                'form_type = "v" AND show_end_date > NOW() AND archived = "n"',
                'order' => 'db_table'
            )
        );

        $this->view->exhibitions = $exhibitions;
    }
}
```

And I know it's correctly linking rows from my `webmaster` table, as I have the following code in my View, and it displays `webmaster_id` values:

**index.volt**

```
{% for exhibition in exhibitions %}
    <li>
        {{ link_to('index/browse/' ~ exhibition.db_table, exhibition.db_table) }}
        <!-- testing below -->
        {% for webm in exhibition.webmaster %}
            {{ webm.webmaster_id }}
        {% endfor %}
        <!-- end testing -->
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is three-part:

1. How can I *only* link `webmaster` rows that have a column `extra_1` as not `NULL`?
2. How can I `count()` the linked `webmaster` rows for each `db_table` (which is unique in `form_settings`)?
3. How can I pass this information through to the View in my `$exhibitions` object so that I can echo the `count()` in Volt syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey and first of all thank you for the nice question formatting.

Excuse me for using examples that use my current database structure. But you can easily update your code.

**1)** You can set additional parameters to the relation definition.

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'Models\News', 'category_id', [
    'alias' => 'news',
    'reusable' => true, 
    'params' => [
        'order' => 'id DESC',
        'conditions' => 'extra_1 IS NOT NULL',
    ]
]);
```

Please note the `reusable` above. When using it, the query runs only once per request. Considering you want to count records and iterate over them its a nice performance boost.

**2 + 3)** Iterating over results in volt and counting:

Controller code:

```
$this->view->categories = \Models\NewsCategories::find();
```

Volt:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.news|length > 0 %} // Do not print categories without articles
    <h3>Category #{{ category.id }} with total of {{ category.news|length }} articles.</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for item in category.news %}
        <li>News #{{ item.id }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above code in my case produces the following output:

> #### Category #4 with total of 4 articles.
>
> - News #3
> - News #4
> - News #5
> - News #7
>
> #### Category #5 with total of 1 articles.
>
> - News #1

Comment: `for category in categories`
`for item in category.news`

NO JUST NO, this will make like A LOT of database queries. If you only need to select news ids then use group_concat to select it with query builder in same row as category and display it properly in volt.

Comment: This was just an example to illustrate @mpdc question. He wanted to know how to pass parameters to model relations and how to count items in volt. No one says that this is the best practice :)